# How to get the type of an expression as a string?

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

I'm having a small problem here. I have a `clang::Expr` object. I want to get the type of that expression as a string. According to the documentation, [`clang::Expr`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html) returns a [`QualType`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1QualType.html). `clang::QualType` has a method called `getAsString()` which returns a string describing that type.

```
// Get the expressions to the left and right of the binary operator.
const Expr *lhs = binop->getLHS()->IgnoreParenCasts();
string typeLhs = lhs->getType()->getAsString();
```

When I type make, it reports an error:

```
remove_memcpy.cpp:110:46: error: no member named 'getAsString' in 'clang::Type'
            string typeLhs = lhs->getType()->getAsString();
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
```

Apparently `Expr::getType()` returns a [`clang::Type`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html), not a `clang::QualType` as expected.

It's weird, in the documentation it days that `Expr::getType()` returns a `clang::QualType`. Perhaps it is because the latest version of the documentation is Clang 9.0.0, but I'm using Clang 6.0.1. Maybe they changed it.

If I have a `clang::Expr`, whose underlying type is `int` or something, how can I get the int as a string, `std::string("int");`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getAsString` does provide a functionality that you're looking for.

The problem with your code is that `Expr::getType` does return `clang::QualType` not `clang::QualType *`. It has an overloaded operators `*` and `->` that return `clang::Type &` and that's why you get this compiler error.

*Long story short*: change it to `lhs->getType().getAsString()`